Dimension of R in QR decomposition
For a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $k<n$, its full QR decomposition is given by
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}Q_1 & Q_2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}R \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The dimensions of $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $R$ are $m\times k$, $m\times (m-k)$, and $n\times n$ respectively. Is that correct?
The economical QR decomposition of $A$ is $\hat{Q}\hat{R}$. The dimensions of $\hat{Q}$ and $\hat{R}$ are $m\times k$ and $k\times n$ respectively. Is that correct?

Yes, everything you've said is correct. Moreover, taking $\hat Q = Q_1$ and $\hat R = R$ would allow you to go from a full QR decomposition (as you've partitioned it) to a economical QR decomposition.

@BenGrossmann I am not sure if $R$ is $n\times n$ or $k\times n$ matrix.

I don’t know what you mean by that. The $R$ that you defined is $k\times n$, and we can indeed guarantee that the rows beneath are zero. If there is some other “R” that you’re referring to, please clarify
